# Evaluate the iterated integral of this function

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:[0, 1]×[0, 1] → R$ be defined by
$f(x,y)= \frac{1}{n}$  if $x=\frac{m}{n}$, $y$ is in rational
and $0$ otherwise

$1.$ Evaluate the iterated integral

$2.$ Is $f$ riemann integrable on $[0, 1] \times [0, 1]$

Can someone help me with this? I am trying to practice integrals in $R^n$ but it's really confusing me.

Answer (score 0):

For each $x,y\in\mathbb R$ define $f_x$ and $f^y$ on $\mathbb [0,1]$ by $y\mapsto f(x,y)$ and $x\mapsto f(x,y)$, respectively. Since $\mathbb Q$ has zero Lebesgue measure, $f_x=0$ a.e. for all $x$ so $$0=\int_0^1 f_x(y)\ \mathsf dy=\int_0^1\int_0^1f(x,y)\ \mathsf dy\ \mathsf dx.$$

A similar argument may be used to show that the other iterated integral is zero.

However, $f$ is not Riemann integrable on $[0,1]^2$. Let $(x,y)\in[0,1]^2$ with $x=\frac pq$, $p\not\mid q$ and $y$ irrational. Let $\{y_n\}$ be a sequence of rational numbers with $\lim_{n\to\infty}y_n=y$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}(x,y_n)=(x,y)$ but $$\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x,y_n)=\frac1q\ne0=f(x,y). $$ This implies that $f$ is discontinuous on a set of positive measure, from which the result follows.

Comment: What exactly are $f_x$ and $f^y$?

Comment: $f_x: [0,1]\to\mathbb R$ where $f_x(y)=f(x,y)$ for all $y$, and vice versa for  $f^y$ (as defined in Folland).